# Descobrir menor valor que está vindo de um excel

Tags: php

Possuo uma planilha que recebe vários valores na mesma linha, podendo eles estarem ambos preenchidos ou apenas um dos valores preenchidos. Então por exemplo:

```
Coluna                 |   A    |   B   |   C     |
Valor                  |  56,00 | 48,00 |  50,00  |  (menor valor = 48,00)
Valor                  |  10,00 |       |         |  (menor valor = 10,00)
Valor                  |  20,00 |       |  22,00  |  (menor valor = 20,00)
Valor                  |        | 15,00 |  17,00  |  (menor valor = 15,00)
```

Onde o espaço em vazio é vazio mesmo no excel.

Tentei pegar o menor valor das seguintes formas

```
  $valor_coluna_a = $field[0]; //equivale a coluna A
  $valor_coluna_b = $field[1]; //equivale a coluna B
  $valor_coluna_c = $field[2]; //equivale a coluna C
  $menor_valor = 999999;
  if($valor_coluna_a < $menor_valor){
     $menor_valor = $valor_coluna_a;
  }
  else if($valor_coluna_b < $menor_valor){
     $menor_valor = $valor_coluna_b;
  }
  else if($valor_coluna_c < $menor_valor){
       $menor_valor = $valor_coluna_c;
  }
```

Nessa tentativa acima, o que eu imaginei que conseguiria pegar o menor valor de uma forma correta não ocorre, qual o erro dessa lógica?

Answer (score 0):

Olá pelo que vi na sua logica o problema e que você esta utilizando **else if** como se trata de 3 comparações deveria ser 3 **if** por exemplo

```php
  $valor_coluna_a = 50;
  $valor_coluna_b = 48;
  $valor_coluna_c = 52;

  $menor_valor = 999999;
  if($valor_coluna_a < $menor_valor){ 
      // Verdade - Entrou Aqui e Atualizou a Variavel
     $menor_valor = $valor_coluna_a;
     // $menor_valor = 50
  } else if($valor_coluna_b < $menor_valor){ 
      // Verdade - Porém não entra aqui como se trata de um if else ele
      // ja entrou na primeira condição portanto não executa mais o resto.
     $menor_valor = $valor_coluna_b;
  } else if($valor_coluna_c < $menor_valor){
       $menor_valor = $valor_coluna_c;
  }
```

melhor maneira de resolver isso seria fazendo 3 **if** assim será feita as comparações devidas.

```php
  $valor_coluna_a = 50;
  $valor_coluna_b = 48;
  $valor_coluna_c = 52;

  $menor_valor = 999999;
  
  if($valor_coluna_a < $menor_valor){ 
     $menor_valor = $valor_coluna_a;
     // Menor Valor = 50;
  } 

  if($valor_coluna_b < $menor_valor){ 
     $menor_valor = $valor_coluna_b;
     // Menor Valor = 48;
  } 
  
  if($valor_coluna_c < $menor_valor){
       $menor_valor = $valor_coluna_c;
  }

  // Menor Valor = 48
```

espero ter ajudado.